# controller method to extract multiple values

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Is it possible that we can use a controller method to extract multiple values under the same parameter name through an annotation at the method parameter part?

Comment: Welcome Re-coder08. To me it is completely unclear what you are trying to achive. Please edit your question to include more details. Maybe you have some code how you are imagining it to work?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your method parameter can be deserialized by implementing your own deserialization annotation, which would be placed on the class definition itself.  Depending on the library in which your @Deserialize dependency resides, research the builder pattern that it requires and implement this in your POJO; there are a few implementations of this annotation.

Answer (score 0):

From the Spring reference documentation : [@RequestParam](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-requestparam)

> Declaring the argument type as an array or list allows for resolving
>   multiple parameter values for the same parameter name.

example , `@RequestParam("names") List<String> nameList`